# Unable to add/remove objects to group due to orphaned SIDs: PrincipalOperationException: An error (1332) occurred

Tags: c#, exception, active-directory, adsi

I need to add/remove objects (users, groups) to a local group on a server. I do this as below and it works fine:

```
Principal adObject = Principal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, login);
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, IdentityType.Name, localGroupName);
groupPrincipal.Members.Add(adObject);
groupPrincipal.Save();
```

Except for the cases when a local group contains some orphaned SIDs (Active Directory users or groups that are already deleted).

[image: Orphaned-SIDs]

In that case i get below exception:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership. The member's SID could not be resolved.
```

This error message appears when i try to add, remove and enumerate members in a local group. While reading current members of a group below workaround works fine:

```
DirectoryEntry group = (DirectoryEntry)groupPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)group.Invoke("Members", null))
{
   ...
}
```

However converting `GroupPrincipal` into `DirectoryEntry` does not solve the issue for adding and removing new members. I have tried three methods below and none of them works:

```
1) group.Invoke("Add", new object[] {@"WinNT://" + domain + "//" + login + ",user"});
2) group.Invoke("Add", new object[] { @"LDAP://" + adObject.DistinguishedName });
3) group.Properties["member"].Add(@"LDAP://" + adObject.DistinguishedName);
```

All three cases above gives the same error:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership.  The member's SID could not be resolved.
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.IsLocalMember(Byte[] sid)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNextLocal()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNext()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollectionEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollection.ContainsEnumTest(Principal principal)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollection.Add(Principal principal)
```

I need to be able to add and remove users to the group without removing those orphaned SIDs. Can someone please suggest me a solution/workaround for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems i found the workaround for the problem:

```
DirectoryEntry group = (DirectoryEntry)groupPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
IADsGroup nativeGroup = (IADsGroup)group.NativeObject; // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706022(v=vs.85).aspx
nativeGroup.Remove("LDAP://" + adObject.Sid.Value);
//nativeGroup.Remove(String.Format("WinNT:////{0}//{1}", domain, ID));
//nativeGroup.Remove(String.Format( "NTDS:////{0}//{1}", domain, ID));
```

If you convert `DirectoryEntry` to native object and cast it to `ActiveDs.IADsGroup` - `Add()` and `Remove()` methods works fine