# Ansible facts: An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership. The member's SID could not be resolved

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to register a `CNAME` inside our Microsoft DNS server using this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: windns
  remote_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}@MYDOMAIN.COM"

  tasks:

  - name: Create alias
    win_dns_record:
      computer_name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      name: "myalias"
      type: "CNAME"
      value: "myhost.mydomain.com"
      zone: "MYDOMAIN.COM"
      state: present
```

I'm stuck on this error when `gather_facts: true`

```
An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership.  The member's SID could not be resolved.
```

```
$ ansible-playbook --check dns_alias.yml --ask-vault-pass -k 
SSH password: 
Vault password: 

PLAY [windns] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [windns]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n  setup: Unhandled exception while executing module: An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership.  The member's SID could not be resolved.\n"}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
windns                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I set `gather_fatcs: false` it **works**.

<s>`CNAME` is not created.</s>. The user is domain admin.

Any hints?

Comment: Are you running this with admin rights? Maybe its related to permission issues or maybe the account you're trying to use its not recognized on active directory or ldap...

Comment: Sorry all.. with `--check` it's obvious that the record is not created. The problem with gather_facts remains.

Answer (score 0):

After some research regarding the error message

> `An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership. The member's SID could not be resolved.`

and your hint

> The user is domain admin

it seems according

- [How to overcome the "The member's SID could not be resolved" error when checking if user is a member of group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050428/)
- [Unable to add/remove objects to group due to orphaned SIDs: PrincipalOperationException: An error (1332) occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224359/)
- and others, [3](https://github.com/lithnet/miis-autosync/issues/103), [4](https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/An-error-1332-occurred-while-enumerating-the-group-membership-The-member-s-SID-could-not-be-resolved?language=en_US), [5](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/workstations/thinkstation-p-series-workstations/thinkstation-p320/solutions/ht510621-error-an-error-1332-occurred-while-enumerating-the-group-membership-the-members-sid-could-not-be-resolved), ...

that the issue is caused not by Ansible but the environment and deleted, renamed or orphaned accounts.